# Can not find selenium webdriver element in HtmlUnitDriver but can find it in Firefox

Tags: selenium, java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

```
    HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
         driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    String baseUrl = "http://www.biletix.com/search/TURKIYE/en#!city_sb:istanbul,date_sb:weekend";
         driver.get(baseUrl);
          WebElement myDynamicElement =
                    new WebDriverWait(driver, 220).until(
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("all_result")));

         System.out.println(  myDynamicElement.getText());



    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 220 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.id: all_result
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: '-PC', ip: '192.168.1.203', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:261)
    at Main.main(Main.java:167)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with ID: all_result
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: '-PC', ip: '192.168.1.203', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementById(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1018)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1715)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1711)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:606)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:911)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$0(ExpectedConditions.java:909)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:238)
    ... 1 more
```

It gives above errors.

But when i use firefox like that,no errors:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String baseUrl = "http://www.biletix.com/search/TURKIYE/en#!city_sb:istanbul,date_sb:weekend";
driver.get(baseUrl);
WebElement myDynamicElement =
                        new WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
                        ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("all_result")));
System.out.println(  myDynamicElement.getText());
```

For html driver, unworking code:

```
  HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
     driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
String baseUrl = "http://www.biletix.com/search/TURKIYE/en#!city_sb:istanbul,date_sb:weekend";
     driver.get(baseUrl);
      WebElement myDynamicElement =
                new WebDriverWait(driver, 220).until(
ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("all_result")));

     System.out.println(  myDynamicElement.getText());
```

I also tried

```
    HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
```

but same

Also did this

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
          capabilities.setBrowserName("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0");
          capabilities.setVersion("24.0");      
          capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capabilities);
```

but still same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved.

As i wanted a headless browser, i tried to use `phantomjs` and i succeed.

```
File file = new File("lib/phantomjs-2.0.0-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");  
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
String baseUrl = "http://www.biletix.com/search/TURKIYE/en#!city_sb:istanbul,date_sb:weekend";
driver.get(baseUrl);
```

Because i dont want to use firefox driver and htmlunitdriver rhino is low for this, i tried phantom and it is really cool. Thanks everyone.